# PhpFarm switch not working

Tags: php, environment, phpfarm

I have just installed [phpfarm](https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm) and compiled a 5.3.0 just for test purpose.
All good so far.

When trying to perform `switch-phpfarm 5.3.0` I get "**ln: failed to create symbolic link `/opt/phpfarm/inst/current-bin': Permission denied**".

Note that I have updated my PATH with inst/current-bin and inst/bin from phpfarm directory.

I have attepted to use sudo (like any other newbie) and I got a "sudo: switch-phpfarm: command not found".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: by using `sudo` you execute binary with other user (root user) and each user has it own PATH variable. Could you try `sudo -E` to preserve environment variable ?

Comment: Same "command not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `bin` directory (`/path/to/phpfarm/inst/bin`) to your `$PATH`.